# Woocommerce Products or Wordpress Service missing in iOS simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

After updating everything with npm i -g cordova ionic and latest xcode. Realised that Slider and Products are loaded in Ionic serve on browser but not in the iOS simulator as well as the App uploaded to store. May I know how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance. Attaching a comparison of Browser vs iOS Simulator
[image: Ionic Serve]
[image: Ionic Cordova Build ios]

Comment: Suspect this will be likely due to a CORS issue. Have you tried [checking with the developer tools](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios#using-safari-web-inspector) to see if there is an error shown?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with custom REST API header in WordPress to override CORS

```html
function my_customize_rest_cors() {
 remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
 add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
  header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
  header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );
  header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With' );
  header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
  header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
  return $value;
 } );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15 );
```